# jQuery table - populate text in cell depending on checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple table with `class=".table"` contain 4 columns with classes

- `.Id`,
- `.description`,
- `.delete` //this is checkbox column ,
- `.flag`

and have a button under this table with `class=".savebtn"`.
What I need: when user check any checkbox cell in `".delete"` column  update flag cell in the same row with text "d" then click `".savebtn"` to delete this row checked, and another issue that user can not save if `".Id"` or `".description"` not filled.

I Try this :

```
$('.table .cf-table-block tbody tr').each(function () {
    $(this).find('input:checked ,.flag input').each(function () {
        $('input:checked').change(function() {
            $(this).closest("tr").find(".flag input").val("d");
        });

        $('input:checked').change(function() {
            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).closest("tr").find(".tableFlag input").val("");
        });
    });

    //to prevent user from saving if ".Id" && ".description" are empty or   not filled
    if ($('.Id input,.description input').val() === '') {
        alert('Code and description must be filled ');
        $('.savebtn').preventDefault();
    }else{

    }
});
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you really want. Plus - can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Please provide your HTML markup.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/61ovcsjf/

Comment: Where are the `Id` and `description` inputs? Your code is incomplete.